# If right click on NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, winforms, right-click, notifyicon

How can I detect if I right click on my NotifyIcon?

I tried this but "Button" gets redmarked.

```
 private void noi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use the MouseClick event instead of Click.

Comment: I just realized that this method works too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NotifyIcon has a ContextMenu property. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

A ContextMenu is not what I want. But I found a way:

```
private void noi_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                LEFTORRIGHT = "left";
            }
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                LEFTORRIGHT = "right";
            }
        }
    private void noi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LEFTORRIGHT == left)
            {

            }
            if (LEFTORRIGHT == right)
            {

            }
        }
```